# Is there an easy way to add GUI search elements to an AWS cloudwatch dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I would like to be able to basically add some GUI drop down and search field elements for a Cloudwatch log-insights search to a dashboard to enable non SQL-savvy admins to change filter and sort options easier based on a few pre-chosen selections. Is this possible without implementing an entirely different tool like Athena?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible with dashboards. The feature set of CW dashboards is fairly limited.

Comment: That's how it seemed to me, just wanted to make sure I wasn't just missing it due to inexperience. Thanks!